# Can I Add "Ctrl" key to my custom android keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, hotkeys

I built an android keyboard with working shift ,enter and spacebar keys but I  can't add a ctrl key to my keyboard .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have not done this, But I think you can simulate `CTRL` key by sending proper codes. for Example `CTRL-A` to `CTRL-Z` and come other have standard ASCII codes as listed [here](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html). It should solve most of your problems even though it does not cover up everything.

In addition, I should say that there is already an app which provides a full keyboard with `CTRL` key on it called [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) and it seems to be [open source](https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard). You may be able to use it to learned how to do this.